# nodejs service is getting exit even after handling it using SIGTERM

Tags: node.js, signals, graceful-shutdown

I am trying for graceful shutdown of nodejs service(which is huge) and hence kept a listener as
`

```
process.on('SIGTERM',async ()=>{
    console.log('EXITING');
})
```

`
As we can see I have not exit the nodejs instance but it exits with no errors when I send SIGTERM.
I want to know why it is getting killed . what are the possible listeners which may be calling an exit internally so that I can make changes accordingly to proceed for graceful shutdown.

I tried with handling it with process.on("exit") , process.on("uncaughtException") but none of them could help me